# Where to hire 2D sprite artists?

Tags: sprites, hiring

I'm looking for high quality original 2D sprite collections which are animated where appropriate.  (IE not simply collections I can buy, we want original work).

I've had a look online but am struggling to find out where I can hire such people!

- Where do I find such people?
- How much should I expect to pay?

Comment: this question is valuable, it should be reopened!

Answer (score 6):

I asked a [similar question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7421/how-much-to-pay-for-artwork-in-an-indie-game) a while back. It was suggested to me to look at the [DeviantArt Job Offers Forum](http://forum.deviantart.com/jobs/offers/) - Credit to André Paramés

Answer (score 4):

The Lost Garden blog ran a post a few months back where game artists could self promote. Quite a nice a list was generated as a result - [List of game artists](http://www.lostgarden.com/2011/03/list-of-game-artists.html#comments)

Answer (score 2):

[The question that lists free existing sprites sets](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20/where-can-i-find-free-sprites-and-images) may not give you want you want *directly*, but you might consider using it to track down the authors of some sprites you like the look of and approach them to see if you can work out a contract with them for some custom sprites.

How much you pay probably depends on the artist, the type of work you want, how you want to handle the process of providing/requesting tweaks to the art, et cetera. To give you an example, while I have not contracted with artists for sprites before, I have done so on logos. I ended up paying anywhere from $50 to $300 for the final logo in both high-resolution vector form (and a few bitmap renders) and the rights to use it where and how I needed to. The final logo was the result of about a week, off and on, of back and forth iteration between myself and the artist.

Answer (score 1):

The [Gamedev.net Help Wanted forums](http://www.gamedev.net/forum/8-help-wanted/) is great place to search. When I've searched for artists in the past (paid and unpaid), I've usually received replies within a couple of hours.

Comment: Here is the new link to them: http://www.gamedev.net/classifieds

Answer (score 1):

The pixelation forum, they are dedicated to pixel art and have a jobs section.
http://www.wayofthepixel.net/pixelation/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try the game maker community, gmc.yoyogames.com

They have quite a few good pixel artists there, quite a few who also will animate.
The downfall is that you have to be very selective about who you pay, because the range of people who say they are "good" ranges all the way down to 8 year old noobs.

However one major benefit, is that for individual pieces of art, you can tend to post a request and get half a dozen to choose from, and payment is very rarely required.

Comment: Thank's for the tip but we're actually a competitor for them so this wouldn't go down too well!