# Where can I find good designers/animators for the graphics of a 2d game?

Tags: graphics, animation, assets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to hire 2D sprite artists?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15256/where-to-hire-2d-sprite-artists)

I've got a little bit of experience in this field already, and I noticed that it's way better to look for animators than graphic designers, because games need explosions, looping sprite sheets, etc. But it would be even better if I could go somewhere and find people with experience in making graphic assets FOR GAMES, not for general markets. Is there some specialized site or something?

Comment: Where to hire 2D sprite artists: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15256/where-to-hire-2d-sprite-artists Please search the site before asking a question.

Comment: Hey Lucas, welcome to GameDev! Please don't be discouraged by the downvote or question closure. We're just trying to keep the site organized for future users. We've included a link to a similar question that should have the information you're looking for. You can read more about [question closure](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#close) on the FAQ.