# What is the cost of custom made 2D game sprites?

Tags: 2d, sprites, costs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much to pay for artwork in an indie game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7421/how-much-to-pay-for-artwork-in-an-indie-game)

I am looking for sprites similar in style to those of [Final fantasy Tactics](http://www.spriters-resource.com/psx_ps2/fft/index.html), but with a much higher resolution that will work well for both a browser and an iPhone.

In terms of animations:

- Walking in 4 directions
- Swinging with 1 hand
- Some sort of "casting animation" (depending on cost I may use the 1 hand swing with a wand).
- Taking a hit
- Kneeling
- Fallen

**How much would something like that cost per sprite?**

Comment: Hi, Michael, and welcome to GDSE. I've removed the backstory about your game, since ultimately it has no real bearing on the question and leaves people having to sift through for what is or isn't relevant.

Comment: In addition, you need to be more specific about what resolution of sprites you're talking about. The price difference between a 32x32 sprite and a 128x128 (with high detail) would be fairly significant. Depending on what you're after though this question might be considered too localised, but if it's generally applicable enough it shouldn't be.

Comment: I don't think this is a constructive question. There are far too many variables to give a reasonable answer.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking what variables am I missing?

Comment: It is not so much that you are missing variables, but that there are many things that go into the cost that would be quoted to you by any given artist. What one artist may quote may not even relate to what another would quote even if they are doing the same work. That is why this question, and questions like it are not a good fit for the Q&A format that this site aims for.

Answer (score 1):

Placing a price is almost impossible because it more or less depends on what sort of deal you work out with whoever you commission to create the art for you.

Comment: Just looking for a ball park, need some info before I approach a designer. Is a full sprite sheet with the above requirments ~20$ ~200$ ~2000$? I can ask the same question to my UI expert, web desiginer, and 3d artist contacts and they can give me at the very lest broad ranges per page / graphic / screen.